# AutoHotkey vs SharpKeys for remapping keys

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey, remapping, sharpkeys

Both [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) can do key remapping, what're the differences between them when used for key remapping? Which one is more stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Sharpkeys** remaps via the registry. It can't remap key combinations and certain scan codes.
- **AutoHotkey**'s [remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) feature is generally not as pure and effective as remapping directly via the Windows registry.

For the advantages and disadvantages of each approach, see [registry remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry).